# Word to describe something both difficult and significant

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe one thing that has the meaning of both difficult and significant. Surely these two words can be used at the same time (a little bit verbose...maybe), however, if **only one single** word is allowed to be used here, which word can I try?

Example:

> For a new person at work, choosing something that is **[both important and difficult]** is the fastest way to grow up.

Comment: Maybe herculean

Answer (score 1):

In a many contexts you could use **challenging**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/challenging)
> *challenging*:
> difficult, in a way that tests your ability or determination:
> synonyms, antonyms, and examples:
> *difficult* - It’s very difficult to find a job in this city.
> *hard* - The exam was really hard
> *complicated* - The instructions were so complicated I just couldn't follow them.
> *complex* - Designing a house is a complex process.

Although the word lays emphasis on the difficulty of the tasks, the examples reveal how it applies to significant tasks such as getting a job, a complex set of instructions, and the construction of a house. It does not apply to trivial tasks, which are unlikely to be difficult or complex. It therefore applies most to significant and difficult tasks, meeting your specification.

Answer (score 0):

[Critical](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/critical).

It is *important*:

> of the greatest importance to the way things might happen

And *dangerous*

> extremely serious or dangerous

which itself implies it is *difficult* to avoid a bad outcome.